# scrapy running the same spider multiple times with a different parameter (start url)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

i have created a spider that fetches all the followings of a twitter screen_name.

i have 1000s of these screen_names and i need to run the SAME spider but with a different screen_name.

The screen_name is used to alter the starting url.

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

screen_names = [...] # from database

for screen_name in screen_names:
    process.crawl(TwitterSpider(), start_urls=["https://mobile.twitter.com/{name}/following".format(name=screen_name)])        

process.start()
```

Right now this is failing with

> 2019-05-19 15:26:17 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on
>   signal handler: >
>
> AttributeError: 'TelnetConsole' object has no attribute 'port'

Comment: you should check documentation for settings for [telnet console](http://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/telnetconsole.html). You can disable it.

Comment: Also, while you didn't ask this, be sure that `screen_name` in that code snippet is already URL encoded, or call `quote()` upon it, and don't just blast text into a URL like that

Comment: Will it run this concurrently?